# Using вести/водить when talking about driving

Tags: глаголы-движения

I would like to know if it is acceptable to use вести/водить as follows, when emphasising who is/was driving :

1. На прошлой неделе мы ездили в Москву, и я водил туда и обратно.
2. На прошлой неделе мы ездили в Москву. Я вёл туда и моя подруга вела обратно.

Alternatively, would it be better to use за рулём?

Comment: you can not and in English-speaking countries that is the reason why native Russian speakers introduced a separate verb - драйвать. It does not substitute "водить", it's used exactly for saying something - "я драйвал и туда, и обратно".

Comment: Lol, @shabunc is totally wrong. "водить автомобиль" is for to describe your ability to drive (умение водить) or regular driving. And "вести автомобиль" for a specific situation  or some case as an example or a singular case.

Comment: @boldnik what  is exactly wrong - that nobody uses verb драйвать?

Comment: @shabunc I've never heard that. It's a very strange word.

Comment: @artptr well, in at least Bay Area and NYC it used a lot.

Comment: @shabunc is a bilingual expat - now we know his secret! :) Yes, it's difficult to separate languages once you fluently speak more than one (and I'm in the same boat).

Comment: I disagree. I am bilingual and speak few more foreign languages. If only you are not lazy to speak in pure language, it's not hard to not mix up them so that you do not create non existing words. Otherwise ты шпрехаешь не по теме.

Answer (score 6):

1.На прошлой неделе мы ездили в Москву, и я водил туда и обратно.
The sentence is incorrect. That was not a repeated action, so водил cannot be used. It was one completed trip and the movement is not multidirectional, not туда-сюда, first туда, then обратно.
На прошлой неделе мы ездили в Москву, и я вёл машину и туда, и обратно.

2.На прошлой неделе мы ездили в Москву. Я вёл туда и моя подруга вела обратно.
This sentence is grammatically correct. I would just insert the object машину and avoid repetition.
Я вел машину туда, а моя подруга обратно.

Alternatively, would it be better to use за рулём?
You cannot say вести за рулем, Only быть за рулём.
По дороге туда за рулем был я, а обратно — моя подруга.
Those are just possible alternatives.

Comment: As a basic level student, I have seen several websites where it is stated that; indeterminate verbs of motion should be used for completed round trips, including single journeys. You indicate that водить cannot be used as the sentence describes only one trip. Am I missing something please?

Comment: @Adam, as a basic level student, don't worry. I disagree with VV that the first sentence is "incorrect". It is not as correct as "вёл туда и обратно" would be, but people say that way all over the place, and it's perfectly understandable.

Comment: @Adam - "Водить" and "вести" are **not** verbs of motions when referring to a car. While in English "to drive" is a verb of motion ('He drove to work'), in Russian "водить" means "to operate a car, to be at the car's steering wheel", but **not** "to _go somewhere_ while operating a car". When describing road trips, the verbs "водить" and "вести" are used _only_ to say who drives, how good the person drives, how long, etc., these verbs are used to describe the actions of the driver, otherwise the real verbs of motion like "ехать / ездить" are used.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how you might say it:

> Я вёл [машину] туда, а моя подруга - обратно.

> Я был за рулём по пути туда, а моя подруга - обратно.

Things to note:

- 'Водил' would be incorrect in this case as it's a multidirectional verb. A delivery man might say to his partner: Вчера водил я, а сегодня будешь ты. ('I drove yesterday, and today you will drive.') 'Водил' would be correct here as they drove in different directions.
- Best to use the conjunction is 'а' (not 'и') since you are comparing two things.
- No need to say 'вела' - it is more natural to skip it and write a dash instead. This is called ellipsis.

Comment: *Я вёл машину туда, моя подруга - обратно.* Is how I'd put it myself. Alternatively, I could say *До Москвы вёл я, обратно - моя подруга.*

Comment: Also don't forget about option "рулить" which is more or less a short version of "быть за рулем". "Туда рулил я, а обратно — моя подруга"